# Como fazer requisições de post/curtidas/compartilhamento de perfis no facebook

Tags: php, facebook

Tenho que fazer um trabalho onde tenho que criar um código que capture amigos/post/curtidas e compartilhamento de uma página no facebook e guarde no Banco de Dados, mas preciso fazer isso com mais de uma página.
Tenho um exemplo que começou dando certo para uma página específica. Mas agora não esta mais dando certo, mesmo eu renovando o token, alguém poderia em ajudar?
Código abaixo:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <?php

            $url = "146659712053598";
            $token="Aqui_Fica_o_Token"
            // Faz a requisição para API do Facebook
            $postagens = file("https://graph.facebook.com/".$url."/posts?access_token=".$token);
            $amigos = file("https://graph.facebook.com/".$url."/friends? access_token=".$token);
            $curtidas= file("https://graph.facebook.com/".$url."/likes?access_token=".$token);
            // Decodifica o retorno em JSON
            $json = json_decode($retorno, false);
            // Retorna o Número de Likes
            echo $postagens[0];
            echo"<br>";
            //echo $amigos[0];
            echo $curtidas[0];
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**OMaths**, vamos lá:

- Está faltando `;` ponto e vírgula no final:

  ```
  $token="Aqui_Fica_o_Token"
  ```
- Em `file("https://graph.facebook.com/".$url."/friends? access_token=`, note que há um espaço entre `friends? access_token`, devendo ser **`friends?access_token`**
- Em `$json = json_decode($retorno, false);`, a variável **`$retorno`** nunca foi declarada

**Considere utilizar cURL ao invés de `file()`:**

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

    <?php

      /**
       * @param $url    URI to page to parse for Open Graph data
       * @return OpenGraph
       */
        function getPage($url) 
        {
            $curl = curl_init($url);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');

            $response = curl_exec($curl);
            $response = json_decode($response, true);

            curl_close($curl);
            return $response;
        }

    // Define valores
    $url    = "SuaPaginaAqui"; // ou ID numérico
    $token  ="ACCESS_TOKEN";

    // Faz a requisição para API do Facebook
    $postagens  = getPage("https://graph.facebook.com/".$url."/posts?access_token=".$token);
    $amigos     = getPage("https://graph.facebook.com/".$url."/friends?access_token=".$token);
    $curtidas   = getPage("https://graph.facebook.com/".$url."/likes?access_token=".$token);

    // Postagens
    echo "<h2>Postagens</h2>";
    if(is_array($postagens) && array_key_exists('data', $postagens))
    {
        foreach ($postagens['data'] as $key => $postagem) 
        {
            echo $postagem['message'] . "<br />";
        }
    }
    else { echo 'Nenhuma postagem'; }


    // Amigos
    echo "<h2>Amigos</h2>";
    if(is_array($amigos) && array_key_exists('data', $amigos))
    {
        foreach ($amigos['data'] as $key => $amigo) 
        {
            //echo $amigo['NAO_SEI_QUAL_CHAVE_USAR'] . "<br />";
        }
    }
    else { echo 'Nenhum amigo'; }


    // Curtidas
    echo "<h2>Curtidas</h2>";
    if(is_array($curtidas) && array_key_exists('data', $curtidas))
    {
        foreach ($curtidas['data'] as $key => $curtida) 
        {
            echo $curtida['name'] . "<br />";
        }
    }
    else { echo 'Nenhuma curtida'; }

    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Testei aqui com minha página e retornou tudo certo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito obrigado Felipe, ajudou e muito, meu código estava bem ruinzinho, kkk vou estudar melhor seu código. Vlw mesmo! ;)

Comment: Opa, hehe, imagina, não há ruim ou bom! É que cURL permite muito maior liberdade! Vote na resposta se ela foi a mais adequada, obrigado!

Comment: Felipe, só uma perguntinha, se eu quiser acessar quem curtiu ou compartilhou uma certa postagem como faço?

Comment: Quem `compartilhou` não tem como (o face não disponibiliza), mas quem curtiu é só acessar `getPage("https://graph.facebook.com/<ID_DO_POST>?access_token=".$token);`, verá várias chaves e informações sobre o post, uma delas é o `['likes']` e `['comments']`